# iterate Write XML problem

Tags: xml, loops

I am new here and to PHP, i am trying to write a xml file whitch had as source a XML file.

When i read the XML and use the echo command I can see al the record of the source XML.

but when i want to write it to a XML file i can only see one record.

I have read al lot of things already:
some thing i found was the use array's, the use of xpath, or simpleXML.
For the code in echo part i use foreach is this possible with DOM elements?

The code is: `

$objDOM = new DOMDocument();

$dom1 = new DOMDocument();

$objDOM->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$objDOM->load("googlepoints.xml"); //make sure path is correct

$photo = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("photo");

foreach ($photo as $value) {
    $album = $value->getElementsByTagName("album");
    $albu = $album->item(0)->nodeValue;

```
$description = $value->getElementsByTagName("description");
$descriptio = $description->item(0)->nodeValue;

$title = $value->getElementsByTagName("title");
$titl = $title->item(0)->nodeValue;

$link = $value->getElementsByTagName("link");
$lin = $link->item(0)->nodeValue;

$guid = $value->getElementsByTagName("guid");
$gui = $guid->item(0)->nodeValue;

$gps = $value->getElementsByTagName("gps");
$gp = $gps->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo "$task :: $detail :: $albu :: $descriptio :: $titl :: $lin :: $gui :: $medi :: $gp  <br>";


// create doctype
$dom1 = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'utf-8');
$dom1->formatOutput = true;

    $collection = $dom1->appendchild($dom1->createElement("collection"));

        // create child element "photo"
        $photo = $collection->appendChild($dom1->createElement("photo"));


        // create child element "album"
        $album = $photo->appendChild($dom1->createElement("album"));
        $album->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$albu"));

        // create child element "description"
        $description = $photo->appendChild($dom1->createElement("description"));
        $description->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$descriptio"));

        // create child element "title"
        $title = $photo->appendChild($dom1->createElement("title"));
        $title->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$titl"));

        // create child element "link"
        $link = $photo->appendChild($dom1->createElement("link"));
        $link->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$lin"));

        // create text node
        $guid = $photo->appendChild($dom1->createElement("guid"));
        $guid->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$gu"));

        // create child element "gps"
        $gps = $photo->appendChild($dom1->createElement('gps'));
        //$gps->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$gp"));
        $gps->appendChild($dom1->createTextNode("$gp"));
```

}
        // save tree to file
        $dom1->save("order12.xml");

```
    //// save tree to string
    //$dom1 = $dom1->save("order77.xml");
```

?>`

Out put of the XML file`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<collection>
  <photo>
    <album>Landschap</album>
    <description>Foto's genomen op een mooie koude winterdag.</description>
    <title>nil</title>
    <link>index.html</link>
    <guid></guid>
    <gps>22°39'5" N 5°40'54" E</gps>
  </photo>
</collection>`

Only there suppose the be 5 of this records.

Can sombody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$dom1` variable needs to be set outside of the foreach loop.

i.e.

```
$dom1 = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'utf-8');
$dom1->formatOutput = true;

foreach($photo as $value) {

     $dom1->appendChild(...);
     ...
}

$xml = $dom1->save();
```

It's only one record because you're overwriting the `$dom1` each time where you have the comment `// create doctype`

Comment: You are the greatest, thank you very much.
I am whatching this for 2 day now and you in 10 min.
Thanks!!!